# How is the function $f(x)=2^x$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

It’s easy to understand the definition of $f(x)=z^x$ when the domain is $\mathbb{N}$: one only has to multiply $z$ by itself $x$ many times. But what does say $2^{1.5}$ actually mean? Surely you can’t multiply 2 by itself a non-integer number of times?

I also know that $e^x$ can be understood to be the sum of a power series, but why does it agree with the actual definition of the value of $e$ to the power of $x$?

Comment: The youtuber 3blue1brown has an entirely different approach to exponential functions. It's explained from 15 min 25 sec into [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ) (the video is made to explain $e^{i\pi} = -1$, so he does mention the complex numbers throughout the video, but it's still worth a watch, and to understand what he's talking about you probably ought to see the whole thing anyways).

Comment: (... or maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU) would be more suitable to explain the idea; most of what he says about $e^x$ works for any other base.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, write $x=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,\,b$ coprime integers, so $2^x=\sqrt[b]{2^a}$. For irrational $x$, a sequence of rationals $x_n$ obtaining $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ gives $2^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{x_n}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is defined as follows

$2^x:=e^{x\log(2)}$